# psql in bash very strange error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, psql

I Have a problem with a psql query in bash.

I really don't know why the PSQL understands the value HUB is a Column.

> psql -q -A -h Some_host
>   -U User -d datashema -p 1111 -t -f query.txt -c 'SELECT id, text FROM great_201704 WHERE id = 10 and
>   text = 'HUB' ;'
>
> ERROR:  column "hub" does not exist in great_201704

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read your single quotes as if they nest:

```
-c 'SELECT id, text FROM great_201704 WHERE id = 10 and text = 'HUB' ;'
   ^---------------------------------1--------------------------------^
                                                               ^-2-^
```

Bash reads them as two single quoted string with a literal between them:

```
-c 'SELECT id, text FROM great_201704 WHERE id = 10 and text = 'HUB' ;'
   ^------------------------------1----------------------------^
                                                                   ^2-^
```

This is equivalent to not having single quotes around `HUB`, which is why psql thinks its a column.

The easiest way to embed one set of quotes in another string is to just use two different types of quotes:

```
psql -q -A -h Some_host -U User -d datashema -p 1111 -t -f query.txt \
    -c "SELECT id, text FROM great_201704 WHERE id = 10 and text = 'HUB' ;"
```